# Could not read JSON Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class org.joda.time.DateTime] from String value

Tags: angularjs, json, html, hibernate, spring-mvc

Produce.java(Entity class)

```
@Column(name="productionStartFrom")
private DateTime productionStartFrom;

@Column(name="lastDateForBid")
private DateTime lastDateForBid;

@Column(name="produceDate")
private DateTime produceDate;
```

html code

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group datepicker">
    <input style="width: 200px;" type="text" class="form-control"
    name="productionStartFrom" ng-model="produce.productionStartFrom" placeholder="Production Starts From"required />

</div>
```

This is my controller class,If type="text" using angular js. I am getting error as mentioned above.

```
@RequestMapping(value ={"/produce"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Produce saveProduce(@RequestBody Produce produce,
        Model model,HttpSession session,BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletResponse
    response,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, SQLException
    {

    System.out.println("Control to spring" + produce);
    System.out.println(produce.getProductionStartFrom());
    }
```

Stack trace

> 2017-03-02 11:19:09 DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving exception from handler [public com.tta.abcd.model.Produce com.tta.abcd.controller.ProduceController.saveProduce(com.tta.abcd.model.Produce,org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.sql.SQLException]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class org.joda.time.DateTime] from String value ('Thu Mar 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'); no single-String constructor/factory method
>    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@13d0b05; line: 1, column: 19] (through reference chain: com.tta.abcd.model.Produce["productionStartFrom"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class org.joda.time.DateTime] from String value ('Thu Mar 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'); no single-String constructor/factory method
>    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@13d0b05; line: 1, column: 19] (through reference chain: com.tta.abcd.model.Produce["productionStartFrom"])
>   2017-03-02 11:19:09 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:999 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
>   2017-03-02 11:19:09 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:976 - Successfully completed request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says:

> Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class
>   org.joda.time.DateTime] from String value ('Thu Mar 09 2017 00:00:00
>   GMT+0530 (IST)'); no single-String constructor/factory method

To Solve the issue you can have setter methods for your entity that takes String as input and create the Joda DateTime objects.

```
public void setProductionStartFrom(String productionStartFrom) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    this.productionStartFrom = formatter.parseDateTime(productionStartFrom);
}
```

Comment: thank you after i changed that code getting error like productionStartFrom"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid format: "Thu Mar 23 2017 00:00:00 GMT+053..."